# RADIUS accounting Stop messages not being sent

Tags: dell, radius, accounting

I have a Dell N2000 series switch upon which dot1x authentication and RADIUS accounting are enabled. I have configured RADIUS accounting to send start and stop messages, but I am only seeing Start messages in the FreeRADIUS server detail logs.

Here is the relevant switch configuration:

```
aaa accounting dot1x default start-stop radius
dot1x system-auth-control
aaa authentication dot1x default radius
aaa authorization network default radius
radius server attribute 8 include-in-access-req
radius server auth 192.168.0.1
primary
name "RADIUS server"
key 7 "omitted"
exit
radius server acct 192.168.0.1
name "RADIUS server"
key 7 "omitted"
exit
```

Can anyone help with this? I do see Stop accounting messages that are send from our WiFi APs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was to use `dot1x port-control mac-based` on each port that you want authenticated.